# How could I add a text into an image in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I want to add a piece of text into an image in UWP. When I use the Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Text in win2D, it just created an image with Text. So how could I add a text into an existed image? Thanks.Like this

[image]

Comment: yap,but the UWP doesn't have graphics...it just has win2D...

Comment: I googled it...http://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2016/03/03/125445

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer solve you problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP image scaling with Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633408/uwp-image-scaling-with-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Trey's comment, we should be able to use Win2d in UWP. 
To install Win2D.uwp, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

`Install-Package Win2D.uwp`

We should be able use the `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync` method to load a bitmap from a stream. Then we can use the `CanvasRenderTarget.CreateDrawingSession` method to return a new drawing session that we can use it to draw the image and text to the drawing session.

At last we should be able to write the `CanvasRenderTarget` to the file.

For example:

```
var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
var sourceFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (sourceFile == null) { return; }
var device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
var image = default(CanvasBitmap);
using (var s = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, s);
}
var offscreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(
    device, (float)image.Bounds.Width, (float)image.Bounds.Height, 96);
using (var ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
{
    ds.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ds.DrawText("Hello world", 10, 10, Colors.Blue);
}
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
var savepicker = new FileSavePicker();
savepicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("png", new List<string> { ".png" });
var destFile = await savepicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
using (var s = await destFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, s);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        (uint)offscreen.Size.Width,
        (uint)offscreen.Size.Height,
        displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
        displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
        offscreen.GetPixelBytes());
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: yap:) thank you very much although I had fixed that.